# Tablesorter only sorting first column and not others

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am having trouble using TableSorter on my website. The information in the table is being pulled from a database, and I want more than one column to be sortable, but for some reason only the first column will sort. Has anyone else ever encountered this problem?

Initializing: (yes I meant to do those two columns as non sorting)

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            1: { 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            2: { 
                sorter: false 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
    });
```

Table displaying information:

```
<div>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Conference Name</th>
          <th>Website</th>
          <th>Dates</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>State</th>
          <th>Interests</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
       </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('', '', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_select_db("", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Submissions", $link);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

//echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
<tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['confName']; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $row['website']; ?></td>  
          <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $row['state']; ?></td>   
          <td><?php echo $row['interests']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['cost']; ?></td>   
</tr>
<?php
    }
}
mysql_close($link);
?>

</tbody>
     </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using to populate and initialize tablesorter.

Comment: I think the HTML is malformed, remove the `<tr><td>` immediately before the `<?php` block.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the `<tr><td>` tag as suggested and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 <table class="tablesorter" data-sortlist="[[0,0],[0,1]]">
```

[0,0] first line, first column
[0,1] first line, second column